# jQuery DataTables: show "loading..." while the table is initializing

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables and it's working well. I just want to show a text message while the table is being initialized.

I am not using server side.

How can I do it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".table").DataTable({
        "bFilter": true,
        "lengthMenu": [ 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 200, 500, 1000 ],
        "columnDefs": [{ targets: 'no-sort', orderable: false }],
        "pageLength": 50,
        "language": {
            "processing": "Loading..."
        },
        "initComplete": () => {
            $(".table").show();
        }
    });
});
```

I tried with preinit but no luck, and I also do not want to keep displaying the html if there is no request for datatables, something like `beforesend`.

Comment: When already having HTML `table` in DOM ...which you somehow forgotten to add to your question, who shall be able to read a message that will be displayed for a bunch of milliseconds?